Requesting User Consent for Calls.AccessMedia.All for an application, but problem with AdminConsentRequired
I have a web application that functions as a notetaker for Microsoft Teams. Essentially, I need to use the Calls.AccessMedia.All scope for this application to access Microsoft Teams recordings. The problem is, a user cannot consent to this scope without an admin approving the request.
Has anyone ran into an issue like this, and if so, how did you solve it? Is there some logic that is best practice for situations like this, when high-privilege scopes are needed that users cannot consent to? Thanks for the help.

Could you share the API permission blade of your registered application and edit the question?

Could you please share which document you are following for accessing Microsoft Teams recordings?

Please check below solution!

@Gabedillin Is this below solution works for you?


To use the Calls.AccessMedia.All scope for this application to access Microsoft Teams recordings. The problem is, a user cannot consent to this scope without an admin approving the request.

As mentioned in this MSDocument,
Unfortunately it is not possible to access the  Calls.AccessMedia.All Application type API permission without granting  Admin Consent, As it is an high-privilege Microsoft Graph API scope.
NOTE:

User Consent: Users can consent only to low-privilege  scopes for their account.

Admin Consent: Requires admin consent to grant consent for the entire organization or to specific user for high-privilege scopes.


To read the Microsoft Teams recording you need to have OnlineMeetings.Read.All API permission which allows  the app to read the properties and relationship of online meetings including recording information with Granting Admin Consent.
While  Calls.AccessMedia.All  Allows the app to get direct access to media streams in a call and if you need to access this API need to grant Admin Consent as it is an high-privilege scope.
I registered an Microsoft Entra ID application and granted admin consent like below:

Generated access token using below parameter:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id = <client_id>
client_secret= <client secret>
grant_type = client_credentials
scope = https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Decode the access token on http://jwt.ms and Ensure OnlineMeetings.Read.All  should present.
To get the meeting recording:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/onlineMeetings/<meeting-id>/recordings
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/onlineMeetings/<meeting-id>/recordings/<recording-id>

References:
OnlineMeetings.Read.All
Calls.AccessMedia.All
